# Rails HABTM - How to call method on an associated in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Taletid model I have:

```
def beregn_pakke(x)
@total_price << x.talei
end

def calculate_total(tal, sms)
  @total_price = []
  self.pakkes.each{|pakke| pakke.beregn_pakke(pakke)}
end
```

There is a HABTM between pakkes and taletids.

Here is the problem:

```
self.pakkes.each{|pakke| pakke.beregn_pakke(pakke)}
```

I want to create a loop that uses the `beregn_pakke(x)` for any associated pakke.

But it calls for a instance method named beregn_pakke in the pakke model which I don´t want. It should use the `beregn_pakke(x)` method in the Taletid model.

`talei` is a column in my pakkes table.

I want to be able with the `beregn_pakke(x)` method in the Taletids model. To access any column for the given pakke.

How do I use the `beregn_pakke(x)` method in the Taletid model for the associated pakkes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def calculate_total(tal, sms)
  @total_price = []
  self.pakkes.each { |pakke| beregn_pakke(pakke) }
end
```

You're explicitly calling it *on each `pakke`* when you write `pakke.beregn_pakke(pakke)`.

That said, consider something like (untested):

```
def calculate_total(tal, sms)
  @total_price = pakkes.collect { |p| p.talei }
end
```

Or one of the `sum` methods, which will do the work via SQL.

Comment: How do I then use the beregn_pakke(x) in the Taletid model for each associated pakke?

Comment: @Railsbeginner The first example *did* use it--you said `calculate_total` was also in the `Taletid` model.

Comment: I need to use the beregn_pakke(x) that is in the Taletid model for each pakke because I am doing, some calculation in the method. And then adding it to the @total_price array.

Comment: @Railsbeginner The first example *does* use it. If `calculate_total` is in `Taletid` as you said, I'm not sure what the confusion is.

Comment: Sry did not see it thought you did write the same.. (It is late)